# Run engine RSpec/Cucumber tests in the client app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, rails-engines

I have mountable rails engine `Users`:

```
users/
  ...
  features/
    ...
  specs/
    dummy/
    controllers/
    models/
    factories/
    ...
```

I have a client app `MySite`, which uses the `Users` engine:

```
my_site/
  app/
  ...
  features/
    ...
  specs/
    controllers/
    models/
    factories/
    ...
  Gemfile
```

Gemfile:

```
gem "users", git: "..."
```

Is it possible to run engine `rspec/cucumber` tests in the `MySite` app instead of the mock?
If so, what is the best way?

Comment: See this https://gist.github.com/chrisgaunt/1121879, maybe it can help

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this for two reasons:

1. The User engine is its own project. *It* should work in isolation in a certain way. Adding these tests to any project the User engine is included in does not make sense. Why not run all the specs of all the gems you include in your project as well?
2. If you have specific acceptance criteria for *your application*, add cucumbers for that to your project. That way, if you decide to ditch the User engine in the future with something else, you can still verify your application behaving as expected. If you'd included the cucumbers from the engine, then those criteria would have been lost as well.